# Magento Url key for different languages

Tags: php, magento

I have created a a product in magento 1.4.1.1. and it have given different Url key for each languages. When i go to product details page, i got its link in English and Italian languages. but i got 404 error in French store view. When i typed its product url key in French , then i can view its details in french. From these i understood that each url key is not loading while switching each languages. Please help to resolve these . i have enable mod_rewrite engine and also enabled search engine friendly urls in admin side.

Regards
Deepu

Comment: Can you post your languages URLs?

Comment: itality :
http://sevenam.com/dsc/index.php/base-girevole-diametro-mm-210-bianca?___store=it&___from_store=da

Francais:
http://sevenam.com/dsc/index.php/plateau-tournant-diametre-210mm-blanc?___store=fr&___from_store=it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that all your store views are working fine.

You might get '**404 Not Found**' page if you manually try to edit the url for any particular store. Like:-

**This will lead to '404 Not Found' page**

```
http://your-product-url?___store=fr&___from_store=fr
```

**Correct URL**

```
http://your-product-url?___store=fr&___from_store=it
```

**Correct URL**

```
http://your-product-url?___store=fr&___from_store=en
```

Point to notice is:-

**___store** = the current store being displayed

**___from_store** = store displayed previously before the current store

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your support.. I just found a temporary solution for the issue by editing the store.php file and updated the server Thats the reason why it worked for you now.. The issue I found was, returning of same query string while we swtich languages.. I just resolved by taking the corresponding  url of selected category or product and passing it directly to $query variable in store.php file. I am not sure whether it is a good solution for this issue.. but just resolved it by this method for the time being.. Will surely update you if I find a better way to correct it.